# Load error: File 'mFFH'

Tags: java, servidor

Buenas, estoy intentando ejecutar un programa Java que obtiene datos desde un servidor, a través de un file server. Tengo toda la configuración de la conexión, pero al ejecutarlo me aparece este error: 
**Load error: file 'mFFH'
error code:173, pc=0, call=1, seg=0
173 called program file not found in drive/directory**
Esto se da cuando intento loguearme y validar si existe el usuario para el sistema cobol, es decir, cuando intenta acceder al programa cobol del servidor. 
Si alguien sabe como solucionar o por que se debe este error estaré muy agradecido.
**OBS.** No agrego la etiqueta cobol porque necesito 150 puntos para crearla y solo tengo 130.

Comment: Al parecer no puede encontrar el programa. Asegúrate de estar usando rutas absolutas y no relativas.

Comment: Si, al parecer si, ese archivo no encuentra, ya investigue mucho sobre el tema, incluso en el foro de microfocus cobol, que es el distribuidor de la IDE y nada, lo unico que se es que es un .dll y que viene a ser un filehandler. Según la documentacion ya viene con el servidor, pero no se en que directorio. Pero bueno, vamos a seguir investigando a ver que encontramos